# Absolute java beginner. I cannot use a returned variable

Tags: java

This assignment is to calculate the cost of a hospital visit. I am trying to ask the user what the prices for the "overnightCharge", "medicationCharge", and "labCharge" are. I then try to use the input to add them together in the method called "total". Next, I try to print the resulting/returned variable from "total" method in the main method by typing `System.out.println("Your total charge is:   " + total(totalCost)`. I thought `total(totalCost)` would retrieve the variable returned by "total" method.

```
package hospitalstay;
import java.util.Scanner;
/* total charges
if overnight charges
medication charges
lab charges
ask user if new patient*/

public class HospitalStay {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Your total charge is:   " + total(totalCost); // i want to print the "totalCost variable" returned by the "total" method.


}

public static double overnightCharge () {// asking user for overnight charge
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your overnight charge");
    double overnightCharge;
    overnightCharge = sc.nextDouble();
    return overnightCharge;
}

public static double medicationCharge() {// asking user for medication charge
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your medication charge");
    double medicationCharge;
    medicationCharge = sc.nextDouble();
    return medicationCharge;
}

public static double labCharge() {//asking user for lab charge
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("What is your lab charge");
    double labCharge;
    labCharge = sc.nextDouble();
    return labCharge;
}
public static double total (double medicineCharge, double labCharge, double overnightCharge) {
    double totalCost;
    if (overnightCharge == 0) {
        totalCost = (overnightCharge + medicineCharge + labCharge); //Calculating all three charges
    }
    else {
        totalCost = (medicineCharge + labCharge);
    }
    return totalCost;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have changeв the total method to

```
public static double total () {
        return overnightCharge() + medicineCharge() + labCharge();
    }
```

Also change main method to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Your total charge is:   " + total());
}
```

Comment: typo in `return vernightCharge()`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong inputs to `total`, change your `main` to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Your total charge is:   " + total(medicationCharge(), labCharge(), overnightCharge()));
}
```

Also, in your `total` method, you don't need the `if` condition, so you can simplify it to:

```
public static double total(double medicineCharge, double labCharge, double overnightCharge) {
    return  (overnightCharge + medicineCharge + labCharge);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you've defined three parameters for method "total," but you are specifying only one argument in your main method:

```
total(totalCost)
```

to minimize the number of things that you need to change in your code, I would simply change the total() method to:

```
public static double total() {
    double totalCost = overnightCharge();
    totalCost += medicationCharge();
    totalCost += labCharge();
    return totalCost;
}
```

and in your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Your total charge is:   " + total();
}
```

Comment: `total` is still overcomplicated

Comment: Also, `double totalCost += overnightCharge();` has errors

Answer (score 0):

**"Explanation why your code didn't work as desired: "**

- You have created a function **total()** which **takes 3 arguments** i.e **(double medicineCharge, double labCharge, double overnightCharge)**

  ```
  public static double total (double medicineCharge, double labCharge, double overnightCharge) {

          return totalCost;
      }
  ```

> But when you are calling this function in your **main()** you are only passing it a single argument that is total(**totalCost**).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Your total charge is:   " + total(totalCost); // i want to print the "totalCost variable" returned by the "total" method.


}
```

- You have also made a typo mistake "medicineCharge"

**You can try something like this to achieve your desired output :**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hospital {
    static Scanner input;
    private static double overnightCharge, medicationCharge, labCharge,
            totalCost;

    public static double takeInput() { // single function to take input
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        return input.nextDouble();
    }

    public static double overnightCharge() {// asking user for overnight charge

        System.out.println("What is your overnight charge");
        overnightCharge = takeInput();
        return overnightCharge;
    }

    public static double medicationCharge() {// asking user for medication
        // charge

        System.out.println("What is your medication charge");
        medicationCharge = takeInput();

        return medicationCharge;
    }

    public static double labCharge() {// asking user for lab charge

        System.out.println("What is your lab charge");
        labCharge = takeInput();

        return labCharge;
    }

    public static double total() {
        overnightCharge();
        medicationCharge();
        labCharge();

        if (overnightCharge == 0) {
            totalCost = (overnightCharge + medicationCharge + labCharge); // Calculating
                                                                            // all
                                                                            // three
                                                                            // charges only when overnightCharge = 0  
        } else {
            totalCost = (medicationCharge + labCharge);
        }
        return totalCost;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Total :" + total());
    }

}
```

> **Note: I have also reduced the code for calling scanner again again.**